# Adding rows dynamically in UITableView and setting scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

Dynamically adding rows on click of a button at index path n-3. In my table view by default there are total six rows 4 contains textfields and other two contains button(Add more and Save). Adding buttons at location above last two rows.

```
-(void)addMoreButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
rowCount=rowCount+1;

int section = 0;
long row = rowCount;

NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row-3 inSection:section];

[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] beginUpdates];
[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] endUpdates];

    NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowCount-1 inSection:0];
    [(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];   

}
```

The problem arises when rowCount reaches more than 8 and scrollToRowAtIndexPath method called then cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called twice.
Once called by insertRowAtIndex that passes index n-3 and second time when scrollToRowAtIndexPath is called it passes index n-1 that runs the condition when

```
if (indexPath.row == rowCount-1)   //  This is index for last row that contains save button and this condition match thus instead of adding textfields it starts adding save button.


if (indexPath.row == rowCount-2)  //  This is Add more button.

if (indexPath.row < rowCount-2)  //  This is for adding textFields.
```

Please guide for above. And feel free to ask if any query. I am stuck in it from last two days.

Update: cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier;
CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
UITextField *textField_SocialProfile;
UIButton *button_AddMore, *button_AddToMyCon;

UIImageView *imageView_Add;

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    linelable=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height+9, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 0.5)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:linelable];
    [linelable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.2f]];

    if (indexPath.row < rowCount-2)
    {
        textField_SocialProfile = [[UITextField alloc]init];
        textField_SocialProfile.tag=indexPath.row+501;
        NSLog(@"textField_SocialProfile.tag %ld",(long)textField_SocialProfile.tag);

        textField_SocialProfile.frame = CGRectMake(70, (tableView.rowHeight - 20)/2, 230, 30);
        textField_SocialProfile.delegate = self;
        textField_SocialProfile.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                textField_SocialProfile.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ktagInstagram attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
                break;
            case 1:
                textField_SocialProfile.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ktagFacebook attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
                break;
            case 2:
                textField_SocialProfile.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ktagTwitter attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
                break;
            case 3:
                textField_SocialProfile.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Linkedin" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
                break;
            default:
                textField_SocialProfile.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Social Networking" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
        }

        textField_SocialProfile.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
        textField_SocialProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        textField_SocialProfile.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [textField_SocialProfile.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        [textField_SocialProfile.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];


    if (intEditSave==1) {
        [textField_SocialProfile setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [textField_SocialProfile setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

        imageView_Add = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.instagram.com/";

                if (dataSourceArray.count > indexPath.row) {
                    textField_SocialProfile.text = [[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]] length] != 0) {
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                         if([textField_SocialProfile.text isEqualToString:@""])
                        {
                            textField_SocialProfile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.instagram.com/%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]];
                        }
                    }else{
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.instagram.com/";
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];
                textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.facebook.com/";

                if (dataSourceArray.count > indexPath.row) {
                    textField_SocialProfile.text = [[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]] length] != 0) {
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                        if([textField_SocialProfile.text isEqualToString:@""])
                        {
                            textField_SocialProfile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.facebook.com/%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]];
                        }
                    }else{
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.facebook.com/";
                    }
                }                    break;
            case 2:
                imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];
                textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.twitter.com/";

                if (dataSourceArray.count > indexPath.row) {
                    textField_SocialProfile.text = [[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]] length] != 0) {
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                         if([textField_SocialProfile.text isEqualToString:@""])
                        {
                            textField_SocialProfile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.twitter.com/%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]];
                        }
                    }else{
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.twitter.com/";
                    }
                }                    break;
            case 3:
                imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];
                textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.linkedin.com/";

                if (dataSourceArray.count > indexPath.row) {
                    textField_SocialProfile.text = [[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]] length] != 0) {
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];
                         if([textField_SocialProfile.text isEqualToString:@""])
                        {
                            textField_SocialProfile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.linkedin.com/%@",[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"]];
                        }
                    }else{
                        textField_SocialProfile.text=@"www.linkedin.com/";
                    }
                }                    break;
            default:
                imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                if (dataSourceArray.count > indexPath.row) {

                    textField_SocialProfile.text = [[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SocialProfile"];}

                break;

        }

        NSString *socialName= textField_SocialProfile.text;


        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.instagram.com/"].location!=NSNotFound) {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.linkedin.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.facebook.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.twitter.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.instagram.com/"].location!=NSNotFound) {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.linkedin.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.facebook.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.twitter.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];

                }
                else
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.instagram.com/"].location!=NSNotFound) {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.linkedin.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.facebook.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.twitter.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];

                }
                else
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.instagram.com/"].location!=NSNotFound) {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.linkedin.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.facebook.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.twitter.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                }
                break;
            default:
                if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.instagram.com/"].location!=NSNotFound) {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instagramIcon.png"];
                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.linkedin.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedinIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.facebook.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebokIcon.png"];

                }
                else if ([socialName rangeOfString:@"www.twitter.com/"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterIcon.png"];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView_Add.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myconIcon.png"];
                }
                break;
        }


        imageView_Add.frame = CGRectMake(30, (tableView.rowHeight - 8)/2, 15, 15);
        textField_SocialProfile.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];

        [cell addSubview:imageView_Add];
        imageView_Add = Nil;
        [cell addSubview:textField_SocialProfile];
        //textField_SocialProfile = Nil;

    }

    else if(indexPath.row == rowCount-2)//Add more button
    {
        //        NSLog(@"textf: %@",textF.text);

        NSLog(@"AddMore: %ld",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"AddMore: %d",rowCount);

        button_AddMore = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [button_AddMore setTitle:ktagAdd_More forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddMore titleLabel].font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];
        [button_AddMore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddMore addTarget:self action:@selector(addMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button_AddMore.tag = ktagbutton_AddMore;

        button_AddMore.frame = CGRectMake(90, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 140, 30);
        button_AddMore.center=CGPointMake(90+70, 22);
        [button_AddMore setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addMore_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:button_AddMore];
        linelable.hidden=NO;

        if(intEditSave == 1)//Editing is complete
        {
            button_AddMore.enabled=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            button_AddMore.enabled=YES;
        }
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == rowCount-1)//Save fields button
    {
        NSLog(@"Save: %ld",indexPath.row);
        NSLog(@"Save: %d",rowCount);

        button_AddToMyCon = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [button_AddToMyCon setTitle:ktagAdd_to_MyCon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddToMyCon titleLabel].font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];
        [button_AddToMyCon setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddToMyCon addTarget:self action:@selector(save_Fields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button_AddToMyCon.tag = ktagbutton_AddToMyCon;

        button_AddToMyCon.frame = CGRectMake(90, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 140, 30);
        button_AddToMyCon.center=CGPointMake(90+70, 22);

        [button_AddToMyCon setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(234.0f/255.0f) green:(134.0f/255.0f) blue:(59.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0]];
        button_AddToMyCon.layer.cornerRadius=4;
        [cell addSubview:button_AddToMyCon];
        linelable.hidden=YES;

    }

}
    return cell;
}
```

The trouble is if i set dequeReusable property to nil, then this problem solves and current data starts vanishing when scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a behaviour of tableView datasource and delegate methods. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called when `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` because when table scroll to show cell which is not visible on screen then method performs reuse cell, So `cellForRowAtIndexPath` load content for new visible cells.

It is default and correct behaviour, you can not by pass it.

Now you need to manage app requirement with it. I don't think so that this behaviour makes any loop hole to your requirement.

Because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a method which is called several times and you can not limit any constraints here.  Still leave a comment if you think that your expected behaviour is not achieved.

**Edit:**

While creating a sample demo for you, I figure out one point - may be it will sort out your problem quickly.

In below line animation was not working proper:

```
[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Change row animation `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft` to `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`, see below updated line:

```
[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Still if this will not solve your problem you have sample demo here...

For the sake of simplicity I have limit control and focus on functionality.

### [Dynamic Cell Creation Demo - Click Here](http://jmp.sh/Srq0ZVx)

[image]

Comment: Hi, i updated the code with cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Please check that, the trouble is if i set deque Reusable property to nil, then this problem solves and current data starts vanishing when scrolled.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @iPhone6 - I have created simple demo for you check edited answer.

Comment: Hey buddy, where is demo, is there any attachment.

Comment: The big title "Dynamic Cell Creation Demo - Click Here" in answer is a link for the demo.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts brother, but i think you misunderstood the issue. I mentioned i my first point that"if i set deque Reusable property to nil, then this problem solves and current data starts vanishing when scrolled" even when i changed that animation property that doesn't affect to functionality. And this demo is also not useful because my issue is with the textfields in the rows they can't hold the data or can't create new rows with textfields. Please look again. Thanks.

Comment: The observation in demo code is that you have to create `CustomCell` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. So make one , add all controls in that and perform other operations. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code raise this issue. Also you are adding controls in `if(cell == nil)` means it will only add controls when new cell created. Again read my answer, tableView reuse cell. So this condition not works for reusing cell and this happens on scrolling.